# Golang httptest TLS bad certificate error on test certificates

Tags: go, https, certificate

I am completely baffled and I can't see what the problem is here as to why Golang httptest package on TLS says the test certificates are bad.

All I am trying to do is mock out a HTTPS request with response. So, nothing fantastic. In normal http everything is fine but if I change to HTTPS it breaks and the good message is Bad Certificate, then further down it gives me the current date and time and then says it is after a time that is 2 hours before.

I have a shell script that generates the certificates for me before the tests are run and I have checked them, they are correct with no errors.

Why is this problem happening?

Comment: Is there any reason to not use https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httptest#Server.Client to get a client which is guaranteed to trust the httptest's certs? I mean, there's no need to even mess with gnerating certs.

Comment: «it is after a time that is 2 hours before.» I think this is fishy. Is the local time on your machine has +2 or -2 hours offset to UTC?

Comment: I am working off a windows 10 VM machine in azure. So, I don't have control of the underlying host